# Can I omit a subject in If-clauses?

Tags: sentence, conditionals, clauses, subjects

I came across a sentence on Cambridge Dictionary. It says

> If found guilty, he faces six months in jail.

They omitted "he is" right ?
And can I say

> If (my computer is) broken , I will fix it.

And can I also use this grammar with an active sentence

> If (you) punch him, he gets hurt

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This kind of ellipsis only works if the omission consists of the subject and a form of the verb '*to be*' **and** the omitted subject appears in the main clause either as the subject or the object.

> If (**he** is) found guilty, **he** faces six months in jail.
>    *(subject-subject)*
>
> If (**my computer** is) broken, I will fix **it**. *(subject-object)*

Of course, the preceding sentence is only intelligible if it is clear from the context what the **it** is. And some might object that the "*if broken*" clause is a [dangling participle](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/09/26/participles-how-not-to-dangle/).

The sentence *If punch him, he gets hurt* does not omit the verb *to be*. It is both unintelligible and ungrammatical. A grammatical alternative is:

> If (he is) punched, he gets angry.

Comment: I don't think "If (my computer is) broken, I will fix it" is correct, I would say "If broken, it will be fixed (by me)". That is, subct-subject is ok, subject-object is not.

Comment: @Rusty Core. I agree that the second sentence is somewhat problematic, particularly for those who have a strong aversion to dangling participles. There's a good article on the topic on Slate:  https://slate.com/human-interest/2014/09/the-real-problem-isn-t-dangling-modifiers-it-s-ambiguity.html

Answer (score 1):

The first example only works if the context makes it clear who is being talked about.

*Fred Bloggs is in court on a charge of [whatever]. If found guilty, he faces six months in jail*

The 'If' phrase has to refer to the subject.

*My computer is very slow. If broken, it will have to be sent away for repair* is grammatical, if not very idiomatic. So, no, your third example doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence from dictionary, the subject is exact in the second sentence but in your first example, it's not exact what you are talking about. "If broken,  i will fix the computer" would be better,  i guess

Comment: No, because the 'If' phrase has to refer to the subject of the sentence. Your suggestion literally means "If I am broken, I will fix the computer."